# Minimal phase space volume $h^3$ out of Heisenberg's principle

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, volume

So the explanation in my text book is this: we have a phase space volume $\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z\Delta p_x\Delta p_y\Delta p_z$. Now they state that [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) states $\Delta p_x\Delta x\geq h$ so our minimal phase space volume is $h^3$.

However, shouldn't Heisenberg's uncertainty principle be $\Delta p_x\Delta x \geq \frac{h}{4\pi}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a particle in a box (3D infinite square well), then the density of momentum states *per unit volume* is given by
$$ g(p)\ dp = g_s\ \frac{4\pi p^2}{h^3}\ dp,$$
where $g_s$ is a spin degeneracy factor (e.g. $g_s=2$ for electrons, protons etc. because they can have 2 spin states per momentum state). This means that the volume of phase space occupied by one momentum state must be $h^3$.

The treatment you give in your question is a rough attempt to justify this result in terms of the (usually) more familiar Heisenberg uncertainty principle. Such a treatment cannot be exact since for a particle in a 1D infinite potential well, the product of uncertainty in momentum and position is actually given by
$$ \Delta p \Delta x = \frac{h}{4\pi} \left(\frac{n^2 \pi^2}{3} - 2\right)^{1/2}$$
(see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#Position_and_momentum)), where $n \geq 1$ is the principle quantum number and thus the product of momentum and position uncertainty is always bigger than $h/4\pi$ and would then need to be averaged in some way over all the momentum states.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've seen a more thorough derivation of the density of states which indeed makes more sense. 

Good to know that the heisenberg derivation is not exact.