# Particle states per phase space volume of a quantum gas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, phase-space, volume, quantum-statistics

> Consider a quantum gas in a box with volume $V=L^3$ and temperature $T$, consisting of spinless bosons. Explain why the number $dN$ of "single-particle states" in a "momentum space volume" $d^3p$ is given by $$dN=\frac{1}{Vh^3}d^3p.$$

I don't know at all how to solve this question. Do I have to use Heisenberg's uncertainty relation to somehow count the states in a "phase space volume"? Using that I get $\Delta x \Delta p \geq h$, so one "phase-space-volume" is always greater than $h^3$. Shouldn't we then have $dN=\frac{d^3x \ d^3p}{h^3}$?

Comment: This might help you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186258/

Comment: And why not transfer the $V$ from  the denominator to the numerator in the task?

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist Yeah it's probably supposed to be there, this was from an old examn so I didn't thinkt there would be an error.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would try is to get the solutions of a 3D box for Schrödinger equation. You are going to obtain this relations:

$$k_x=\frac{\pi}{L}n_x$$
$$k_y=\frac{\pi}{L}n_y$$
$$k_z=\frac{\pi}{L}n_z$$

Derive both sides in each equation. Now use the fact that the number of $dN=dn_x dn_y dn_z$. You should get the answer you looking for.

EDIT: It's weird that the number of states decrease with V. I'm 99% sure it  has to be wrong.

To get your answer use the De Brogilie relation $\vec{p}=\hbar\vec{k}$. Remember you need to do the calculation in the eight octants, not only the first one. The number of states will be then:

$$dN=\frac{V}{8\pi^3 }dk^3=\frac{V (2\pi)^3}{8\pi^3 h^3}dp^3=\frac{V}{h^3}dp^3$$

where I've used that $\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}$.